# Google Sign in not responsive

Tags: android, flutter, google-oauth, google-signin

I have a Flutter app where I use Google Sign in.
In general, everything works fine but some (~5-10%) of the users are experiencing a really weird bug where they just cannot click on Google account when signing in.
There is no error in Crashlytics. And I cannot reproduce it but it does happen to some of the users.

On the video you can see that user is clicking on his account, but the dialog is not responsive.

[image]

I'm running the following code however, I have no idea how to debug nor how to reproduce the issue.

```dart
GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']).signIn()
```

Has anyone experienced anything like that? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly the same and quite old but it, and the issue it mentions, could be related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227085/flutter-google-sign-in-stuck-after-selecting-account

Comment: If you are running this on the debug build then it might have a problem just add a log to that if it is throwing success of returning the user information it might work in the release build which is signed. (accessToken)
I was facing this there are certain limitations by google for the release build and debug build please check that

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using? Are you sure that user has proper internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```dart
    GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: [
        'email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
      ],
    ).signIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this same issue some time ago and i just upgraded the google sign in package from (https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) and solved my issue.

**I Hope this things are solve your issue.**

Comment: I'm using the latest version :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest updating the package version.I have faced the same issue some time back it was solved by clearing the packages and cache.

run
`flutter clean`
then run `flutter pub cache clean`
. next run `flutter pub upgrade`

this might solve your issue.

Comment: I'm using the latest version :(